# Docker desktop for mac not honoring buildkit disable (buildkit: false)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker desktop v4.19.0 for macOS.  I have the following config in settings > docker engine

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": false
  }
}
```

Specifically `"buildkit": false`

No matter what I do, any time I start a container, a buildkit container - in the format `buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0` - is created.

This only happens on my intel iMac.  I have a M1 Macbook Pro which does not exhibit this behavior. Both are the same version of Docker Desktop.

The intel iMac hasn't always been doing this.  It has happened recently (last 3 months or so).

How do I prevent Docker desktop from creating this buildx/buildkit container?

Answer (score 0):

Completely uninstalling all files related to Docker per https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-docker-on-mac solved it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 10, when using Docker Desktop.
Like you, `"buildkit": false` did not solve my problem.

In my case, the container name of the `moby/buildkit` image was `zealous_montalcini`.

Finally, I discovered that there was a folder called `buildx` in `C:\Users\<user>\.docker`, and when I removed the `zealous_montalcini` file in both `buildx/activity` and `buildx/instances`, it actually removed the buildx buildkit successfully.

[image]
[image]